# BMI calculator :ValueError: could not convert string to float: X

Tags: python

So I've decide to learn to code in python last week, as i had experience with C++ and C# and to be honest, was nothing for me. Python on the other hand does. I've decided to make a BMI calculator, cause I've found it easy. Problem come at the if section. I've added code I've found but it just switched one error to another. Any tips will be appreciated :)

Sidenote: This is just a part of a bigger code that tells you how many grams of eg. fats you should take. But at the moment I am stuck here.

```
    try:
        weight = float(input("""What is your weight (Kg)?
                           >>> """))

        height = float(input("""What your height (m)?
                            >>> """))
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect input")
        continue
    bmi = weight / (height * height), 2

    print(name + " your BMI is " + str(bmi))

    bmi2 = float('.'.join(str(ele) for ele in bmi))
    if bmi2 < 18.4:
        print("You are under weight by BMI standards!")
    elif bmi2 == 18.5 and bmi2 <= 24.9:
        print("You are normal weight by BMI standards!")
    elif bmi2 == 25 and bmi2 <= 29.9:
        print("You are over weight by BMI standards!")
    elif bmi2 == 30 and bmi2 <= 34.9:
        print("You have obesity (class 1) by BMI standards!")
    elif bmi2 == 35 and bmi2 <= 39.9:
        print("You have obesity (class 2) by BMI standards!")
    elif bmi2 > 40:
        print("You have obesity (class 3) by BMI standards!")
```

Comment: Please constantly preceding indent in your code.

Comment: What is your formula for `bmi`?

Comment: Provide a full error traceback

Comment: BMI formula is bmi = weight / (height * height), 2 | 

without the added code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kohaku/FitCalcul.py", line 31, in <module>
    if bmi < 18.4:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float' | 

with the added code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kohaku/FitCalcul.py", line 31, in <module>
    bmi2 = float('.'.join(str(ele) for ele in bmi))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '18.591130340724717.2'

Comment: btw. version of Python is 3.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, so lets go through them:

1. On line 9 you had an illegal `continue` statement. You were not in a loop or `switch`.
2. On line 11 (12 before edits) you used a variable named `name`. I am guessing you defined this outside of the provided code, but if not, you must define it.
3. You are outputting BMI as a `tuple`. This can be traced back to line 9 (10 before edits), where you are defining it as `weight / (height * height), 2`. Remove the `, 2`.
4. I don't know what you are trying to do using a variable `bmi2` defined on line 13, you can simply use `bmi` in those functions and should work properly.
5. You also need to change all of your `==` operators in the section about BMI standards to >=, and the `and` statements to `or`.

Comment: The whole program runs in While True: loop, there is a menu for metric and imperial system and also a quit that Break.

Comment: Ah. If you are doing something like that, put it in your code. We thought you just had unnecessary indents and such.

Comment: I have also noticed that I've used `and`, not `or`.

Comment: I am sorry, using stack for the first time. Next time I'll provide the whole code! :)